# Rails - Formatted log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a tool / website that allows you to copy / paste log data and have it formatted for you?  1 option is to simply copy / paste in to a text editor, but was wondering if there were better options to make log data more readable. A use case would be understanding / making readable the json response of an api call

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it but a quick Google search turned this up: `https://github.com/timberio/timber-ruby`

Comment: This is a useful tool but was looking for something more like this: https://codebeautify.org/ruby-formatter-beautifier - are there better versions of this out there!